# how to return data by ajax in php/mysql/jquery webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

content.php

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var srt=$("#cal1Date1").val();//start date
        var end=$("#cal1Date2").val();//end date

                $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/show.php",
            data: {srt:srt,
                end:end
                    },
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            complete:function(response){

                console.log(response.responseText);
            }}); })}
```

the above code is sends the data to show.php which queries the date range

show.php

```
    include_once "connector.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `testtable` WHERE  `Request Date` BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date' "   ;

            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {                         
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 echo  $row["Order ID"]; }
                        mysqli_close($db);
                   ?>
```

and the above code filters the result by the date range we provided.
it prints all the filtered  'Order Ids'

now I want to know is how can I send all these order id back to content.php?
so i can manipulate the data there.

Comment: What you will echo in show.php will be available in ajax success callback.
...
dataType: "json",
success:function(r){
 //+ r is the content echo from show.php
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to json_encode to return the response to ajax(content.php)

```
include_once "connector.php";
$startdate=$_POST['srt'];
$enddate=$_POST['end'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `testtable` WHERE  `Request Date` BETWEEN 'start   date'=$startdate AND 'end date'=$enddate "   ;

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {                         
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $orderid[]= $row["Order ID"]; }
          mysqli_close($db);
}
     echo json_encode(array('OrderID'=>$orderid));  
           ?>
```

In ajax Complete function get the response as below,

```
complete:function(response){

      $rtndata=response.responseText;

          var dat1a=jQuery.parseJSON($rtndata); 

                   var result=dat1a.OrderID;
                   console.log(result[0]);
                   console.log(result[1]);
             console.log(result[2]);
    }
```

Comment: their is some problem with json response because data is coming like this `{"orderid":["95695","4428516","4428517"]}` but when i put `console.log(response.orderid);` result is undefined

Comment: use  var data=jQuery.parseJSON(response);

              console.log(data.orderid);

Comment: `{"Order ID":["95695","4428516","4428517"]}` this is the response I am Trying this ` console.log(data[1].);` so that it would print _95695_ but it is just printing undefined

Comment: did u get data value as {"Order ID":["95695","4428516","4428517"]}.

Comment: Yes that's is what I am getting

Comment: try var result=data.Order ID;console.log(result[0]);